# How to load a TrueTypeFont with different parameters? LibGDX

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx, truetype

The way I have been doing it so far is copying the same font, saving under another name and loading it with different parameters. I am trying to develop an app in LibGDX and by saving the font as different files takes more memory than necessary. Isn't there a way of loading 1 font multiple times, each time with different parameters?

Comment: what do you mean by copying the same font ? Are you dealing with BitmapFont `.fnt` file or with `.ttf` file . ?

Comment: .ttf. In order to use a font with different paramteres, I simply copied the existing one, pasted it in the same folder under a different name and loaded it with other parameters

Comment: you can use same .ttf file and generate different font by changing FontTypeParameter attribute only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look of this example, I am creating a list of BitmapFont object having different size by simply changing attributes of `FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter`.

```
public class MainGame extends Game {

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    BitmapFont font[];
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        camera=new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false,400,640);
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

        int size[]=new int[]{5,8,10,13,15,20,30,40,50,60};

        font=new BitmapFont[size.length];
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("BUBBLEGUM.TTF"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

        parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
        parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear; // used for resizing quality
        parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;

        for(int i=0;i<size.length;i++){
            parameter.size=size[i];
            font[i]=generator.generateFont(parameter);
            font[i].getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
            font[i].setColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        generator.dispose();   // Don't forget to dispose
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,0,1);

        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        spriteBatch.begin();
        for (int i=0;i<font.length;i++)
           font[i].draw(spriteBatch,"LIBGDX FONT",10,100+i*55);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
         camera.setToOrtho(false,width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
         spriteBatch.dispose();
         for(BitmapFont bmfont:font)
              bmfont.dispose();

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/extensions/FreeTypeFontLoaderTest.java

Comment: Ok, but if I am loading my font with an Asset Manager, would I do the same?

Comment: yes you can, At the end you've bitmapfonts, load it into AssetManager.

Comment: I am using a FreeTypeFontLoader to load the fonts and parameters, instead of a FreeTypeFontGenerator. Should I change it? And when you load the font from the asset manager, it asks for the fonts' location, so how would you load the same font, but with different parameters? Sorry for asking so many questions, but I am very confused

Comment: How do I do that? 0.0