# libgdx-freetype new lib issue with letter spacing

Tags: android, libgdx, freetype

I had a game with the old version of FreeType lib. For some reason, I update the lib but there was some change to do, so I did.
But after I have a problem with the letter spacing. I show you 2 images, before and after:[image]
[image]

there is some code (of the last image):

AssetLoader.java:

```
public static BitmapFont font12;
public static GlyphLayout font12G = new GlyphLayout();

font12 = generator2.generateFont(parameterText); 
        font12.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        font12.getData().setScale(0.04f, 0.04f);

public static String leaderboards = "LEADERBOARD";
```

GameRender.java:

```
private void drawLeaderMenu() {
        AssetLoader.font12G.setText(AssetLoader.font12, AssetLoader.leaderboards);
        AssetLoader.font12.draw(batcher, AssetLoader.leaderboards, (GameScreen.gameWidth / 4)
                - (AssetLoader.font12G.width) / 2, circle.getR().y + 20);
    }
```

I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Do you _need_ the newer version? You are not supposed to use `setScale` on your font, instead change the size of the font by changing the `size` variable for your `parameterText`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set size in `FreeTypeFontParameter` instead of font scaling.

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("BUBBLEGUM.TTF"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear; // used for resizing quality
parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;

parameter.size=20; 
font=generator.generateFont(parameter);
font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
font.setColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

 generator.dispose();   // Don't forget to dispose
```

Comment: if i change the size i have low resolution, i want to change the scale so I can have better resolution

Comment: pass size according to your viewport dimension, that will generate font in what size you needed.

Comment: ideally we should not use scaling in any way

Comment: try with small value in size, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43550851/3445320), I've tested with different size

Comment: if I want good resolution I have to use big size (like 400) and then scale so I can have good result

Comment: why so, what's your viewport dimension ?

Comment: cam.setToOrtho(true, 120, gameHeight); width:  float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();      
        gameWidth = 120;
        gameHeight = screenHeight / (screenWidth / gameWidth);

Comment: width is fixed height is variable that depends on which factor ? Hopefully you're setting `batch.setprojectionmatrix(camera.combined)`

Comment: i add this line but nothing change

Comment: I can't change the viewport size because the entire game does not work anymore

Comment: there's some way to use the old library so i can work?

Comment: give me some time, i'll check. I am outside right now. by the way which version of freetype are you using ?

Comment: I don't know, I think the last because I've made the libgdx project with the setup tools about a week ago

Comment: You can check version in `build.gradle` file of root project

Comment: gdxVersion = '1.9.6'

Comment: I tested, I don't have any spacing problem with `1.9.6` version

Comment: with big size and then scale?

Comment: how I generate big size font ? by default generator generate 16 pixels's font

Comment: but you don't scale?  I use size = 400 and then scale it

Comment: can u explain me how to use the older libs? the older libs work

Comment: you want to use `font.setScale()` instead of `font.getData().setScale()` ?

Comment: if its possible yes, in the older libs this method works well

Comment: Use version `1.5.5`, for that replace `1.9.6` with `1.5.5` as gdxVersion in root `build.gradle` file refresh gradle dependency. Changes are from LibGDX 1.5.6 version.

Comment: don't' work, the app crash and I don't understand why

Comment: may be some version compatibility, download gdx-setup version [1.5.5](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/libgdx-1.5.5.zip) and create new project after that copy all your code and resource in newly created project.

Comment: I add to my question the log result, thanks for your patience

Comment: you can't add log in Answer section you may edit your question and add there, it violate stackoverflow rule.

Comment: Possible reason of this exception that, in later version many cpu architecture support added to libgdx and still you're using `build.gradle` that created by latest version, so try to create new project with old version. I've already added a link in previous comment for 1.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Try setting font.setUseIntegerPositions(false), the default is true.